# Breaking into your friend's computer

Tags: rhyme, steganography, computer-puzzle

You're trying to break into your friends laptop. 
However, his computer is password protected. 
Luckily he has a password hint on his computer.

> The password you are looking forˏ 
>  is not easy like one, two,
>   three, four˳ 
>  A bit more complex than you would like， 
>  and
>   if you get it wrong, you would get a strike․ 
>  Not even
>   numbers and letters you see‚ 
>  You can probably get it while having some teaǃ

Can you figure out what his password might be?

Comment: Why did you post this? My friend might see this if I fail to break into his computer!

Comment: Ahaha I love it!

Comment: @jwi I removed one of your tags; I don't think it's necessary given your computer-puzzle tag and the fact that this is the only puzzle which currently uses it.

Comment: thats fine! I just added in case people wouldn't have guessed to use rot13(havpbqr)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has to do with

> the weird punctuation you've stuck at the ends of the sentences. Each of the characters are non-standard punctuation marks.

For example,

> In the first line, ˏ is a Modifier Letter Low Acute Accent, which has the Unicode translation U+02CF. 
>  The second ending ˳ is a Modifier Letter Low Ring, which has the Unicode translation U+02F3. 
>  The third ending ，is a Fullwidth Comma, U+FF0C. 
>  The fourth ending ․ is a One Dot Leader, U+2024. 
>  The fifth ending ‚ is a Single Low-9 Quotation Mark, U+201A. 
>  The sixth ending ǃ is a Latin Letter Retroflex Click, U+01C3.

If we take the

> Unicode translations of each

We get the hex string

> 02CF 02F3 FF0C 2024 201A 01C3

If we translate hex directly to text, we get a final password of

> Ïóÿ $ Ã

Comment: Not quite there yet! Very close

Comment: How does this look, @jwi?

Comment: Good Job!!! So quick, gotta make my next one harder!

Comment: @jwi Thanks! That is one disgusting looking password, though ;P

Comment: Mans gotta do what hes gotta do to be secure

Comment: @jwi Obligatory [xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/936/)